# vector derivative of outer product of vector with itself

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the outer product of a $n \times 1$ vector Z with itself, is there a quick way to compute the derivative of this matrix with respect to another $m \times 1$ vector b.

My hunch is

$\frac{\partial Z Z^\top}{\partial b} = 2 \underbrace{Z^\top}_{1 \times n} \underbrace{\frac{\partial Z}{\partial b}}_{n \times m}$

but I cannot show it. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the derivative of a matrix with respect to a vector a tensor of rank $3$?

Comment: Yes - I was just about to reply to my own comment. This is obviously wrong. Derivative of a matrix w.r.t. matrix is a rank 4 tensor, derivative of a matrix with respect to a vector a rank 3 tensor.

Comment: You want something more than$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial b_k} (ZZ^T)_{ij} = \frac{\partial}{\partial b_k} (Z_i Z_j)=\frac{\partial Z_i}{\partial b_k} Z_j + \frac{\partial Z_j}{\partial b_k} Z_i?
$$

Comment: For the case that m = n = 3 this should turn out to be a 9x9 array. 

So then yes, assuming you have a convention for what order to compute i vs j vs k.